# Extracting polygons from road network using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, polygon-creation

I need to extract faces (or polygons) from my road network and calculate their areas.

I mainly use ArcPy.

If it needs to be converted to graph structure, include it as well.

Comment: To clarify, you want to convert your roads (lines) into polygons and calculate their areas?

Comment: yes. in other words, I want to build the polygons surrounded by the segments of the road network.

Comment: To create block polygons from road network lines you would use the road network as the input to the Features to Polygons tool http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003n000000,  The lines need to actually touch or cross and fully enclose an area to form a polygon.  Cul-de-sacs will not split a polygon and will be surrounded within a polygon, because they do not enclose an area.

Comment: I believe the equilavent to what @RichardFairhurst has correctly suggested in QGIS is the SAGA function: **Convert lines to polygons**.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst I think you should copy/paste your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To create block polygons from road network lines you would use the road network as the input to the Features to Polygons tool help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//…, The lines need to actually touch or cross and fully enclose an area to form a polygon. Cul-de-sacs will not split a polygon and will be surrounded within a polygon, because they do not enclose an area.